# How do I lock specific rows on a table for updating only a single one of them?

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

I have Postgres 13.7 database and a process that updates a Type-2 SCD table, specifically one using a 'current_record' column to denote the most recent version of a row.

The insertion of new data on this table and the update of the current_record column all occur within a single transaction, and are (by nature of the process that triggers them) only happening on a small subset of records pertaining to a specific foreign key at a any given time. I'm currently running into an issue where, if two updates are made within milliseconds of each other on the same foreign key, the process that updates the current_record column will set it to True for both records because neither transaction has completed yet, and both see themselves as having the most recent record.

Is it possible to prevent this with some specific type of temporary row-level locks on the specific foreign key or on the transaction itself? I've tried looking into documentation about this, but the sheer amount of info on the types of locks and how they interact with each other makes my head spin.

I've tried:

- Splitting the transaction into two parts, but the issue still occurs because of how fast the timing is between the events
- Creating a reconciliation script that manually fixes the problem (would rather avoid this)
- Creating a constraint to enforce a single True current_record per foreign key, but this slows the process down immensely and isn't viable for me